# Safely save and restore environment variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I have a script that parses a rudimentary `.env` file and exports its contents as environment variables, before taking further action:

```bash
set -eu

test -f .env && load_dotenv

exec ./foobar x y z "$@"
```

However, this results in environment variables defined in `.env` taking precedence over environment variables defined in the user's shell. I want the opposite behavior: I want environment variables explicitly set in the shell to take precedence over anything defined in the `.env` file.

Therefore I was hoping to "save" the current environment before running `load_dotenv`, and then "re-apply" that saved environment after running `load_dotenv`:

```bash
set -eu

user_env="$( env )"

test -f .env && load_dotenv

reapply_env "$user_env"  # ???

exec ./foobar x y z "$@"
```

How do I implement `reapply_env`, such that it can handle arbitrary environment variables? As far as I know, any byte other than `\0` is valid in an environment variable, so I want to make sure that this works for any arbitrary env var. For example, there are legitimate (although unusual) use cases for embedded newlines in environment variables.

I'm open to shell-specific answers, but assume I am using a Bourne-flavored shell (Bash, Ksh, Zsh, etc.).

Ignore security issues. Assume I am operating in a trusted, controlled environment, and that any scenario like "tricking the developer into downloading a malicious `.env` file" involves a broader security problem that's beyond the scope of this question.

Edit: How to avoid overwriting env vars is a great question, but it's not what I'm interested in answering in this particular question. I can post a separate one for that, if there isn't already a duplicate.

Comment: "_I want environment variables explicitly set in the shell to take precedence_" - what about modifying your env loader to avoid setting a variable that's already set

Comment: what does your `load_dotenv` do / how is it implemented? Can you just test there if the variable already exists before loading a new value from the file? Do you care bout the difference between exported shell variables (which end up in the environment of programs the shell runs) and non-exported ones (which don't)?

Answer (score 6):

Bash has ability to test environment variable before setting it.
So you can write your `.env` file like this:

```
VAR1="default value"
VAR2=${VAR2:="default value"}
```

Now, if you have a new session (batch or terminal) and do:

```
$ source .env
$ echo $VAR1 - $VAR2
default value - default value
$ VAR1="my value"
$ VAR2="my value"
$ source .env
$ echo $VAR1 - $VAR2
default value - my value
```

That syntax is described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Both `ksh` and `zsh` have similar ability, with same syntax for the task "assign value to a variable if this variable does not exist":

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=shell-parameter-substitution-in-korn-posix

https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 3):

In Bash (unsure of minimum supported version), the `export` builtin emits a valid script that can be `eval`-ed or `source`-d:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export FOO=$'a\nb'

export > ./user-env.bash

env -u FOO bash -c '
source ./user-env.bash ;
sh -c "printf \"%q\n\" \"$FOO\""
'
```

The output should be:

```
$'a\nb'
```

Zsh also emits a valid script, but it does *not* include any `export` declarations, whereas the Bash version includes `declare -x` at the start of each line. So I am still searching for a Zsh solution.

Comment: Use `export -p` in any POSIX or Bourne-like shell, including zsh, to get output that the same shell can parse (with `export` statements and proper quoting of the values). A POSIX-compliant shell emits output that any other POSIX-compliant shell can parse. Bash is not compliant unless set to POSIX mode: it emits output that it can parse, but other shells can't.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'! It looks like the POSIX documentation is here, including `-p`: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_22

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Linux, you can read `/proc/self/environ` to save the environment variables:

```bash
myenv=()
while IFS= read -d '' -r var; do
  myenv+=("$var");
done < /proc/self/environ
```

Then once you load your env file, use that array to set those values again (assuming the variable names don't contain `=`):

```
for i in "${myenv[@]}";
do
  export "$i";
done
```

Comment: AFAIU, that only gives you the stuff that was in the environment when the shell process was executed, not anything it read later from whatever startup files it reads

Comment: That's what OP wants, I think. My understanding: they set some environment variables in their shell and then run the script shown in the question, which also modifies the environment using the .env file, but they want the values they manually set to take precedence. This way, when they run the script, `/proc/self/environ` will have those values.

Comment: Beware environment variable names are not necessarily mappable to shell variable names. The environment could contain things like `-a=b` or `a[$(reboot)]=c`, or even entries without `=`s such as `-p`.